# disable opengl es textures ios

Tags: ios, opengl-es

How do i temporarily disable textures on opengl es 2.x for ios in the render function?
I am implementing color selection.

I am not using glkit. I am using shaders, so `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` doesn't work, nor did `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you want to achieve. If you disable a texture what do you expect to have in your rendering?

If your shader calculates the color of a fragment based on a Texture sample, if you do not bind any texture, what should it use in place of the texture? A color?

I see 2 options:

A - use 2 shaders, one supporting textures, one using fixed colors (or vertex colors if you load the attribute)

B - use a single shader and pilot the rendering (texture or colors) using uniforms.

The option B offers much more performance.

Edit to first question on how to do it:

```
if (Texture == 0) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);  //red color
} else{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
}
```

Comment: how do i do B ?


here is my shader:
`gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);`

and in my render function i am doing the following:
`glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "Texture"), 0);`

Comment: a simple solution could be:
    if (Texture == 0) {
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);  //red color
} else{
gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
}

Comment: what do you pass to the shader for Texture to be equal to 0?

Comment: I figured it out by using another int in my shader called UseTexture but your example seems to suggest that you can use the sampler2D texture in the if statement. Is that correct?